# Same array with different contents when running in Rails/Apache/Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

I have a single application-wide instance of an object called from two threads.

This object contains an array inside which stores `EventMachine::Channel` objects.

```
require 'em-websocket'

class A
  def self.instance
    @inst ||= self.new
  end

  def initialize
    @channels = []
    puts "init: self=#{self.inspect}\nchannels=#{@channels.inspect}\n\n"
  end

  def add
    @channels << EventMachine::Channel.new
    puts "add: self=#{self.inspect}\nchannels=#{@channels.inspect}\n\n"
  end

  def use
    puts "use: self=#{self.inspect}\nchannels=#{@channels.inspect}\n\n"
  end
end
```

When it comes to use of this array it turns out that the array when called from additional thread contains one channel and no channels when called from Rails controller's action.

`self` and `@channels.object_id` are the same in both cases, only `@channels.length` differs. This thing happens only when running in Apache/Passenger and does not happen for Webrick.

Comment: Could you give an example - what are you trying to do?

Comment: Could you tell us why you are not satisfied with `.object_id`? I don't think you can do what you want to do...

Comment: It shouldn't, please add the use case where it happens.

Comment: Within the same process, `object_id` is unique. From the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Object.html#method-i-object_id): *"The same number will be returned on all calls to id for a given object, and no two active objects will share an id"*

Comment: I think that _that_ is the question you should ask, with code

Comment: @Paul maybe these arrays belong to different processes.

Comment: Try to output `Process.pid` along with the `object_id`

Comment: @Stefan: You were right! They have different PIDs! I rewroite the question completely, cleaned up comments. You can get your points for an answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This thing happens only when running in Apache/Passenger and does not happen for Webrick.

Apache/Passenger starts multiple worker processes, each running a separate application instance, each having its own `@channels` array.

Ruby objects are not shared between processes, but there are other options to communicate like DRb, sockets, queues or key-value stores.

Comment: Could you clarify how the magic happens? I inserted `puts "@inst=#{@inst.inspect}, pid=#{Process.pid}"` before `@inst ||= self.new` expecting `@inst` to be `nil` at least twice - in both processes, but no, in other process `@inst` is already initialized! And when I start a new thread with `Thread.new do` PID is the same inside of thread and before it's definition.

Comment: Processes and threads are quite different. A process can contain multiple threads and data is shared between these threads. You probably call `A.instance` twice from different threads within the same process.

Comment: Yes, I call it more than twice from different threads. How could it be that `@inst` is shared, but `@channels` - not ? P.S. PIDs are different when calling from a thread started in initializer and from a Rails controller. May be this is because of wrapping the code in `EventMachine.run { }` ?

Comment: `@channels` is an instance variable of `@inst`, so it's shared too. But it's only shared within the same process, i.e. `initialize` is called once for each process. Make sure to kill / restart all workers.

Comment: `initialize` is started only when `self.new` is executed and this happens when `@inst` is `nil` and as logs show, it is `nil` only once. `puts` in `initialize` outputs it's string to log only once. Is `sudo httpd stop` enough to kill all workers?

Comment: Could you post your initializer?

Comment: This `A.instance` is being called from two initializers. One is as simple as `A.instance`, nothing more. Other is a complex thing which starts other single-instance object with two threads inside and defines event handlers for it. These handlers call from time to time `A.instance` when TCP socket data arrives. This second initializer is too big to post it here (366 lines).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60072/discussion-between-paul-and-stefan).